# Can't populate using mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, restify, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Why I can't get result while try to populating my scheme (I use mongoosejs). In my case my category, subcategory, subsubcategory scheme don't use _id. I use custom id.

Here's my product scheme:

```
.....
categoryId: {
  type: String,
  ref: 'Catgory',
  required: true
},
subcategoryId: {
  type: String,
  ref: 'Subcategory',
  required: true
},
subsubcategoryId: {
  type: String,
  ref: 'Subsubcategory',
  required: true
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', product);
module.exports = Product;
```

And this is my product controller :

```
'getOne': function(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof req.params.id !== 'string') return res.send({
        'error-code': 3
    });

    Product.findOne({
            _id: req.params.id
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'category',
            select: 'name'
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'subcategory',
            select: 'name'
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'subsubcategory',
            select: 'name'
        })
        .exec(function(error, response) {
            if (error) return handleError(error);
            return res.send(response);
        })
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of right now, you can only `populate` fields using foreign `_id`s. Populating by different fields has been a [heavily requested feature on the mongoose GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562) for quite a while.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I'll try again using another method.